# Idiomatic way to sum a list of Maybe Int in haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there a more idiomatic way to implement the following? I feel like I'm missing a way to get rid of the lambda, but couldn't figure out a way to convert it to point-free. Maybe there is another non-applicative way as well that is more straight forward?

```
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Applicative

foldl (\x y -> pure (+) <*> x <*> y) (Just 0) [Just 3, Just 4]
-- Just 7

foldl (\x y -> pure (+) <*> x <*> y) (Just 0) [Just 3, Just 4, Nothing]
-- Nothing
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'd just use `sequence` from Control.Monad:

```
> fmap sum $ sequence [Just 3, Just 4]
Just 7
> fmap sum $ sequence [Just 3, Just 4, Nothing]
Nothing
```

For the point-free form:

```
sumMaybe :: Num a => [Maybe a] -> Maybe a
sumMaybe = fmap sum . sequence
```

Comment: failed to evaluate with ghci 7.6.3, but works with 7.8.3

Answer (score 17):

The most direct way to eliminate the lambda is to use `liftA2`; it's exactly the code you wrote

```
liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
liftA2 f x y = pure f <*> x <*> y

foldl (liftA2 (+)) (Just 0) [Just 1, Just 2]
```

then we have a few choices for how to propagate the errors. This code has it that any `Nothing` will lead to a total failure. We can do that in two steps like @bhekilr suggested using `sequence`.

```
sum <$> sequence [Just 1, Just 2]     sum <$> sequence [Just 1, Nothing]
Just (sum  [1,2])                     sum <$> Nothing
Just 3                                Nothing
```

We can also use the fact that `(+)` induces a `Monoid` on the values in order to just "ignore" `Nothing`s. Most literally that would be

```
import Data.Monoid

getSum $ foldMap (maybe mempty Sum) [Just 1, Just 2, Nothing]
-- equivalent to, but faster than
getSum . mconcat . map (maybe mempty Sum) $ [Just 1, Just 2, Nothing]
getSum . mconcat $ [Sum 1, Sum 2, Sum 0]
3
```

But we can also use `catMaybe` from `Data.Monoid` to do it in two steps

```
sum . catMaybes $ [Just 1, Just 2, Nothing]
sum [1, 2]
3
```

Comment: Also, note that `(pure f <*>) ≡ (f <$>)` (where `<$>` is the infix form of `fmap`).

Comment: thx @AntalSpector-Zabusky from a new-comer to >=

Answer (score 12):

I think `foldM` works well here.

```
import Control.Monad
sumMay = foldM (fmap . (+)) 0
```

I think it's the clearest as it maps (Ba duh duh ching) to what you'd do in pure code.

Answer (score 3):

You can lift the (+) in the Maybe Monad with:

```
input> fold (liftM2 (+)) (Just 0) [Just 1, Just 2]
Just 3
input> fold (liftM2 (+)) (Just 0) [Just 1, Just 2, Nothing]
Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List
sumMaybes = sum . catMaybes
```

Comment: This doesn't pass the second example (needs to return `Nothing` when _any_ element is `Nothing`)